# Component's tag after <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular-routing

partial1.html

```html
<div class="content">test test</div>
```

main.html

```html
<div class="main">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Let say from `main.html`, route to call `partial1.html`.
And when runtime, the html will be like this:

```html
<div class="main">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   <partial1>
     <div class="content">test test</div>
   </partial>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can remove the extra tag? maybe merge tag, if possible. without break the Angular router.

Also, I don't want to break the CSS. This is important.

```css
.main > .content {}
```

Comment: By 'extra tag' you mean router-outlet?

Comment: can I remove this tag? <partial1>  or any workaround, without need to change my existing CSS code     .main > .content {}. div class content must be child of div class main.

Comment: As I understand 'partial1' tag is a component, so it cannot be removed because it is starting point for that component. Why you must remove it? content class div element is a child of main class div element, so CSS should be valid for this html

Comment: why not change the css to `.main > router-outlet > .content`, or have both `.main > .content` as well as `.main > router-outlet > .content`

Answer (score 6):

I got my own solution.

partial1.html

```html
<div class="content">test test</div>
```

main.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```typescript
@Component({
selector: ".main", //instead of 'partial1'
templateUrl: "./partial1.html",
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

I got the results needed.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="main">
   <div class="content">test test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just the line `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` did it for me. Thanks!